# Javascript Loop array dont display duplicate name and can change if click next button

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var a = ['green','green','green','yellow','yellow','yellow','white','blue']
```

And I will display the array in a loop and the output should be:

```
green


yellow


white
blue
```

It should have space. for example 3 green and it should be display 1 green and next is 2 space or line break

Next what if i have next button the if i click next button the output will be

```
<SPACE>
green

yellow


white
blue
```

Next if i click next button again the output will be

```
<SPACE>
<SPACE>
green
yellow


white
blue
```

next if i have back button the output will be

```
<SPACE>
green
 
yellow


white
blue
```

Please help thanks in advance

I try this

```
var a = ['green','green','green','yellow','yellow','yellow','white','blue'];
let set = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   if(!set.has(a[i])){
      console.log(a[i]);
      set.add(a[i]);
 }else{
      console.log(" ");
 }
```

}

and the output on top is

```
green


yellow


white
blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map()` to create the spaced array and check if the value is the first one in the array using `indexOf()`.

Then use `shift()` and `unshift()` to add or remove space at the beginning

Something like:

```js
var a = ['green','green','green','yellow','yellow','yellow','white','blue'],
    space = ' ',
    res = a.map((v,i) => a.indexOf(v)=== i ? v : space);


document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el=>{
   el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
   
       console.clear()
        let isBack = el.id==='back';
        if(isBack ){
          if(res.length > a.length){
               res.shift()
          } else{
               console.log('At start')
          }
        }else{
           res.unshift(space)
        }
        
        console.log(res)
    });
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {   max-height: 100% !important;}
```

```html
<button id="back">Back</button><button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this task has a following algorithm:

1. you are replacing duplicates with some symbol (in the following example with space)
2. you remove N number of spaces from the array
3. Back and Next button decrement and increment N

The following implementation is not clean but it works.. I hope. :)

```js
class ColorsList {
    constructor(colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
    this.numebrOfDuplicates = this.getNumberOfDuplicates(colors);
    this.removedElementsCounter = 0;
    this.duplicateValueReplaces = ' ';
  }
    
  setUlElement(ulElement) {
    this.ulElement = ulElement;
    return this;
  }
    
  setBackButton(backButton) {
    this.backButton = backButton;
    this.backButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.stepDecrement());
    this.setButtonsState();
    return this;
  }
  
  setNextButton(nextButton) {
    this.nextButton = nextButton;
    this.nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.stepIncrement());
    this.setButtonsState();
    return this;
  }
  
  stepIncrement() {
    if(this.removedElementsCounter < this.numebrOfDuplicates) {
        this.removedElementsCounter++;
    }
    this.setButtonsState()
      .clear()
      .output();
    return this;
  }
  
  stepDecrement() {
    if(this.removedElementsCounter > 0) {
        this.removedElementsCounter--;
    }
    this.setButtonsState()
      .clear()
      .output();
    return this;
  }
    
  setButtonsState() {
    this.backButton && (this.backButton.disabled = (this.removedElementsCounter === 0));
    this.nextButton && (this.nextButton.disabled = (this.removedElementsCounter >= this.numebrOfDuplicates));
        return this;
  }
  
  getNumberOfDuplicates(colors) {
    let numberOfDuplicates = 0;
    let prevColor = '';
    for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
        if(prevColor !== colors[i]) {
        prevColor = colors[i];
      } else {
        numberOfDuplicates++;
      }
    }
    return numberOfDuplicates;
  }
  
  getOuput() {
    const output = [];
    let prevColor = '';
    for(let i=0; i<this.colors.length; i++) {
        if(prevColor !== this.colors[i]) {
        prevColor = this.colors[i];
        output.push(this.colors[i]);
      } else {
        output.push(this.duplicateValueReplaces);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
  
  removeFirstNValues(numberOfSpaces, colors) {
    const removedSpacesColors = [];
    for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
        if(
        colors[i] === this.duplicateValueReplaces
        && numberOfSpaces
      ) {
        numberOfSpaces--;
      } else {
          removedSpacesColors.push(colors[i]);
      }
    }
        return removedSpacesColors;
  }
  
  output() {
    const ouputColors = this.removeFirstNValues(
        this.removedElementsCounter,
      this.getOuput()
    );
    
    for(let i=0; i<ouputColors.length; i++) {
      const liElement = document.createElement('li');
      liElement.innerHTML = ouputColors[i];
      this.ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    }
    return this;
  }
  
  clear() {
    this.ulElement.innerHTML = "";
    return this;
  }
}

const colorsList = new ColorsList([
    'green',
    'green',
    'green',
    'yellow',
    'yellow',
    'yellow',
    'white',
    'blue'
  ]);
colorsList.setUlElement(document.getElementById('colorsListUl'))
  .setBackButton(document.getElementById('backButton'))
  .setNextButton(document.getElementById('nextButton'))
  .output();
```

```html
<button type="button" id='backButton'>Back</button>
<button type="button" id='nextButton'>Next</button>
<ul id="colorsListUl"></ul>
```